# Factoring business growth into linear regression

Tags: microsoft-excel, regression

I am looking to run a pretty basic linear regression in excel with the products price as the Independent Variable and QTY sold as the Dependent variable. I have 5 years of sales data with each row showing month of month growth.

The issue is our company has been in a steady state of growth over that time, 50%, 30%, 40%, and 25% from 2015 to 2019.

Is there anyway to factor this organic growth into the regression?

Thanks

**Weekly Data**

[image: Weekly Data]

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data for better understanding !

Comment: Added image of some of the data. To give more context there is seasonality in the business so some months will see big gains while others might have decently large decreases, Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

*To get the Regression, first check whether Regression Add In is added or not, if not then do the following.*

**Step 1:**

1. Hit File, Option, Add In.
2. Select the Analysis ToolPak & click Go, finish
   with Ok.

**Step 2:**

1. Hit Data tab then select Data Analysis.
2. Find the Regression option and click OK.
3. Next is data selection, hit the Input Y Range
   box and then select dependent variable.
4. For Input X Range select independent variable
   data.
5. Select Output Range.
6. If Required you may select either residual or
   probability graph.
7. Click OK to finish

---

[image]